# Build not failed even when trivy reports a security vulnerability

Tags: github, github-actions, trivy

GitHub Actions build does not fail even when trivy reports a security vulnerability.

Trivy.yaml:

```yaml
name: trivy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
jobs:
  build:
    name: trivy
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Run Trivy vulnerability scanner
        uses: aquasecurity/trivy-action@master
        with:
          scan-type: 'fs'
          scan-ref: '.'
          hide-progress: false
          format: 'table'
          severity: 'MEDIUM,CRITICAL,HIGH'
          exit-code: '1'
          trivy-config: trivy_rule.yaml
```

trivy_rule.yaml:

```yaml
rules:
  - id: rule1
    category: general
    title: Generic Rule
    severity: 'MEDIUM,CRITICAL,HIGH'
    keywords:
      - secret
    regex: (?i)(?P<key>(secret))(=|:).{0,5}['"](?P<secret>[0-9a-zA-Z\-_=]{8,64})['"]
    secret-group-name: secret
allow-rules:
  - id: skip-text
    description: skip text files
    path: .*\.txt
disable-allow-rules:
  - markdown
enable-builtin-rules:
  - aws-access-key-id
  - aws-account-id
  - aws-secret-access-key
  - slack-access-token
  - slack-web-hook
  - github-oauth
  - github-pat
  - github-app-token
  - github-refresh-token
  - atlassian-api-token
  - databricks-api-token
  - grafana-api-token
  - hashicorp-tf-api-token
  - new-relic-user-api-key
  - new-relic-user-api-id
  - new-relic-browser-api-token
  - npm-access-token
```

Output:

```
Total: 8 (UNKNOWN: 0, LOW: 0, MEDIUM: 8, HIGH: 0, CRITICAL: 0)

MEDIUM: Slack (slack-web-hook)
════════════════════════════════════════
Slack Webhook
────────────────────────────────────────
────────────────────────────────────────
   9   locals {
  10     # This is the incoming webhook URL used for all platform alerts, by default it sends to #eng-platform-alerts
  11 [   slack_platform_hook = "*************************************************************************"
  12   }
```

The build should get failed when a security vulnerability is reported.

Comment: Do you see anything about the exit code in the trivy action logs?